# when dividing with demical numbers, what do i do with the remainder?

Tags: arithmetic

Here is the problem.

90.327 divided by 0.08

What i have completed so far for the answer is 1129.

But i cant understand how to complete it because the remainders are so difficuilt.

Please show me how to solve the rest. I really want to understand but its just so hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're working by long division. When you complete the division, if you still have remainder, add a .0 to the end of the dividend. Drop that 0 as you normally would, and continue the long division process, placing more zeroes after the decimal place until you no longer have a remainder.

Comment: If this was meant to be general advice, the last sentence should end, "until you no longer have a remainder or until you have more digits after the decimal than you need, whichever comes first." In the given problem you get a zero remainder soon enough, but in general there is no guarantee you will _ever_ reach zero remainder; for example, try $1.0/0.3.$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{90.327}{0.08}$

I think first remove decimal points.

$\frac{90327}{1000} × \frac{100}{8}$

= $\frac{90327}{80}$

Only divide 90327 by 8 and then shift decimal point one place forward.

You got 11290.875 and then shifting decimal point one place forward because we have 10 in denominator. We have,

= 1129.0875

Comment: Divide 90327 by 8 until you get 0 remainder. And then shift decimal one place forward.